# How can I parse URL from a string with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I hope to get URL from a string, how can I do it with jQuery ?

**For example**

**Source:**  `AAA   http://www.google.com/`            **Target:** `http://www.google.com/`

**Source :** `http://www.msn.com/  This is a comment`  **Target:** `http://www.msn.com/`

**Source :** `BB http://www.twitter.com/ Good site`        **Target:** `http://www.twitter.com/`

**Source :** `Hello https://www.youtube.com`        **Target:** `https://www.youtube.com`

**Source :** `https://stackoverflow.com/74926284`        **Target:** `https://stackoverflow.com/74926284`

Comment: jQuery doesn't have any special string parsing functions. You can do it with an ordinary JavaScript regexp. Google can help you find many URL regexps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regex

```js
const string = "BB http://www.twitter.com/ Good site"
const matches = string.match(/\b(http|https)?:\/\/\S+/gi)[0];
console.log(matches);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take reference from here

> String.prototype.indexOf()

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf

```js
var string = "Hello https://www.youtube.com";
var url = string.indexOf("https://");
var resurl = string.substring(url);
console.log(resurl);
```